# Orbit diagram of a quadratic map

Tags: plotting, nonlinear

I am very new to Mathematica. I am trying to draw an orbit diagram of the quadratic map $f(x) = r - x^2$ for $r <= 2$. I have the following idea for a program:

For each value of $r <= 2$:

- Iterate $f(x)$ starting with $x_0 = 0$ and store values in list.
- Plot the last elements of the list against $r$.

I am having a lot of trouble with the implementation. Hope you can help me!

Comment: Try using the `Nest` command and the `Function` command to perform the iterations.

Comment: For this to be meaningful, iterating the function would have to generate a sequence that converged to a fixed point. In which case, `FixedPointList` would provide the list. However, this does not generally occur. For example, with `r = 1` the sequence oscillates between `0` and `1`. Similarly, for `r = 1.1` the list eventually oscillates between `-0.0916079783099617` and  `1.0916079783099617`

Comment: Similar questions have been answered before, see: [113777](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113777/creating-a-bifurcation-diagram-of-the-logistics-map), [132405](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132405/trouble-with-plotting-a-bifurcation-diagram), [13723](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13723/strange-error-in-bifurcation-diagram), [5123](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/mathematica-bifurcation)

Answer (score 3):

```
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Partition[NestList[r - #^2 &, 0, 500], 2, 1], 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> 1], {{r, 1.8}, 0,  2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Re *How would you draw the r, x plane?*

```
lpp = ListPointPlot3D[Table[Flatten /@ 
   Thread[{r, Partition[NestList[r - #^2 &, 0, 500], 2, 1]}], {r, 1, 2, .1}], 
   AxesLabel -> {"r", Subscript[y, t], Subscript[y, t + 1]}, BoxRatios->1] /. 
   Point -> Line;

planes = Graphics3D[{Opacity[.25], EdgeForm[], 
   Table[InfinitePlane[{{k, -1, -1}, {k, -1, 1}, {k, 1, 1}}], {k, 1, 2, .1}]}];

Show[lpp, planes, BoxRatios->1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This helped me very much in understanding the ways of Mathematica. How would you draw the r, x plane?