# plotting and manipulate plot for logistic model (recursive function)

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, modeling

For a larger project on chaos, I am trying to write a short program that graphs the logistic model with different constant values, in this case the constant being "r".  A) Is there a way to use Table to graph more than just integer values of R from 1 to 4?  B)  Is there a way to use Manipulate to visually drag between different values of r to to display chaos?

```
logistic = Function[n0,

iList = {};
xList = {};

x[0] = 0.01;

For[i = 1, i <= n0, i = i + 1,

x[i] = r*x[i - 1]*(1 - x[i - 1]);

AppendTo[iList, i];
AppendTo[xList, x[i]];

];
]


grapher = Function[
data[];

For[r = 1, r <= 4, r = r + 0.1,

logistic[50];

data[r] = Transpose@{iList, xList};

Clear[iList];
Clear[xList];
];
]

grapher[]
```

The two lines below are what I was using to try and attempt to plot the data lists with no luck.

```
Table[ListPlot[data[r]], {r, 1, 4}]

Manipulate[ListPlot[data[r]], {r, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: Ad A) `Table[i,{i,1,2,0.2}]` gives `{1., 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.}`.

Comment: Thanks!  That answers one of my questions.  Now if I can just figure out a way to label each of these graphs in the table.  Plot Label doesn't seem to work within the table...

Answer (score 4):

`Nest` and its 'relatives' are useful for these purposes. I suggest searching this site for logistic map and bifurcation diagrams. I post this as illustrative. The bifurcation diagram is a slight change to [Vitaliy Kaurov's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5129/1997).

```
lp[u_, pt_] := 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.002], Red, pt}, 
  GridLines -> {{{u, Blue}}, None}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400]
f[r_, x_, n_] := NestList[r # (1 - #) &, x, n];
cw[lst_] := Catenate[{{#1, #2}, {#2, #2}} & @@@ Partition[lst, 2, 1]]
Manipulate[Column[{
   ListPlot[f[p, x0, 100], PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 1}}, 
    Joined -> True, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 400],
   Plot[{f[p, x, num][[-1]], x}, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 400, 
    MeshFunctions -> (f[p, #, num][[-1]] - # &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
    MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}, 
    Epilog -> {Purple, PointSize[0.02], Point[f[p, x0, 1]], 
      Line[cw[f[p, x0, 10]]]}]
   , lp[p, pts]}], {x0, 0.01, 0.99}, {p, 2, 4, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {num, {1, 5, 10}}, 
 Initialization :> (pts = 
     Point /@ 
      ParallelTable[
       Thread[{r, 
         Nest[r # (1 - #) &, Range[0.01, 0.99, 0.01], 1000]}], {r, 2, 
        4, 0.01}];)]
```

[image]

`f` generates a list of the iterations of the logistic map including initial x.