# Trouble with plotting a bifurcation diagram

Tags: plotting

I have the function $f(x)=x^3 + a x$ and I have to plot a bifurcation diagram for values of $a$ between 0 and 2. I have used the code below but it doesn't seem to work for me:

```
ListPlot[ParallelTable[
Thread[{a, Nest[x^3 + ax &, Range[0, 1, 0.01], 1000]}], {a, 0, 2}], 
PlotStyle -> PointSize[0]]
```

Was wondering if anything is wrong with the code?

Comment: 1) `ax` is not the same as `a*x`.  2) You need to use `#` instead of `x` in `Nest`.  3) Is this for the differential equation `x'[t]==f[x[t]]` or the difference equation `x[t+1]==f[x[t]]`?

Comment: You've got terrible overflows; see what's happening with `NestList[#^3 + 0.1 # &, 0.5, 500]`. Additionally, you should reference [where you took the piece of code you're trying to adapt](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5129/22013).

Comment: Many thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The longterm behaviour of this map is either going to zero or blowing up to infinity. Hence the bifurcation diagram is just a set of points that hit "walls" progressively leftward as a increases.

To gain insight:

```
f[a_, x_] := x^3 + a  x
roots[a_] := {x, x} /. Solve[f[a, x] == x && x >= 0, x]
nf[a_, x_, n_] := 
 Catenate[{{##}, {#2, #2}} & @@@ 
   NestList[{#[[2]], f[a, #[[2]]]} &, {x, f[a, x]}, n]]
Manipulate[
 Module[{arrows = {Red, Arrowheads[{{0, 0}, {0.03, 0.6}, {0, 1}}], 
       Arrow[##]} & /@ Partition[nf[a, c, n], 2, 1]},
  ListAnimate[
   Table[Plot[{x, f[a, x]}, {x, 0, 2.5}, PlotRange -> Table[{0, 1}, 2],
     Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.03], Point[{c, f[a, c]}], 
       Point[roots[a]], Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[roots[a]], 
       arrows[[1 ;; step]]}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"a = ", a}]], {step, 1, Length[arrows]}], 
   AnimationRunning -> False]]
 , {{c, 0.1, "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)"}, 0, 1}, {n, 
  Range[5]}, {a, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

**Inspired by bills**

The following modifies the function to $x^3- a x$ and illustrates behaviour for parameter values $a$ 0 to 3. To run clear variables:

```
f[a_, x_] := x^3 - a x
roots[a_] := {x, x} /. Solve[f[a, x] == x, x]
nf[a_, x_, n_] := 
 Catenate[{{##}, {#2, #2}} & @@@ 
   NestList[{#[[2]], f[a, #[[2]]]} &, {x, f[a, x]}, n]]
Manipulate[
 Module[{arrows = {Red, Arrowheads[{{0, 0}, {0.03, 0.6}, {0, 1}}], 
       Arrow[##]} & /@ Partition[nf[a, c, n], 2, 1]}, 
  ListAnimate[
   Table[Plot[{x, f[a, x]}, {x, -2, 2}, 
     PlotRange -> Table[{-2, 2}, 2], 
     Epilog -> {Black, PointSize[0.03], Point[{c, f[a, c]}], 
       Point[roots[a]], Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[roots[a]], 
       arrows[[1 ;; step]]}, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
     PlotLabel -> Row[{"a = ", a}]], {step, 1, Length[arrows]}], 
   AnimationRunning -> False]], {{c, 0.1, 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(x\), \(0\)]\)"}, -2, 2}, {n, Range[5]}, {a, 
  0, 3}]
```

[image]

and the bifurcation diagram (100 iterates):

```
tu = Tuples[{Range[1, 3, 0.01], Range[-1, 1, 0.1]}];
nst[a_, x_, n_] := Nest[f[a, #] &, x, n]
ta = {#1, nst[##, 100]} & @@@ tu;
ListPlot[ta]
```

[image]

or stepping starting value by 0.01:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can draw the bifurcation diagram pretty straightforwardly. First, define the iteration:

```
Clear[x, a];
x[a_, n_] := x[a, n] = x[a, n - 1]^3 + a x[a, n - 1];
x[a_, 1] := RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}];;
```

With a little checking, the iteration has interesting dynamics for `a` between about -3 and 0, hence:

```
all = Flatten[Table[seq = x[aa, #] & /@ Range[1000];
    seq1000 = Union[seq[[900 ;; 1000]]];
    Thread[{ConstantArray[aa, Length[seq1000]], seq1000}], 
            {aa, -3., -0.5, 0.001}], 1];
ListPlot[all, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

When `a` is positive, the iteration diverges, as you can see from a linearization argument.

Comment: beautiful...+1. I posted my answer to illustrate why the behaviour in the OP parameter range was causing 'problems' :)

Answer (score 3):

A direct fix of the posted code: change `x` to `#`, change `Range[0, 1, 0.01]` to `Range[-1, 1, 0.01]` for completeness, change the range of `a` to be `{a, -3, 0, 0.01}`, and `Catenate` the sublists:

```
ListPlot[Catenate@
  ParallelTable[
   Thread[{a, Nest[#^3 + a # &, Range[-1, 1, 0.01], 1000]}], {a, -3, 
    0, 0.01}], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0]]
```

[image]